# Excel VBA Compare two lists in Sheet 1 & 2 Column A, then combine the matches' adjacent cells in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two lists of information, each list is a different length and only one column will have matches (column A). I have a list in sheet 2 and need to find the matching results in sheet 1 and then combine the adjacent information from sheet 2 and sheet 1 into sheet 3.

I have searched everywhere for something close to what I require, but can't seem to find anything that works. I have written some code but it only returns one result.

```
Sub search()

Dim srch

For srch = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(srch) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(srch) Then
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, "a") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(srch, "a")
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, "b") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(srch, "b")
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, "c") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(srch, "c")
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, "d") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(srch, "d")
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, "e") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(srch, "e")
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, "f") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(srch, "a")
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, "g") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(srch, "b")
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, "h") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(srch, "c")
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(, "i") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(srch, "d")
    End If

 Next

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me please, even point me in the right direction and I can change the code to fit my needs.

Thank you for any help in advanced.

Comment: When you say adjacent information, is this fixed or dynamic in sheets 1 and 2? Would be useful if you had some sample data